# fstab pass value for non root partitions

Tags: partition, fstab, fsck

If I open `/etc/fstab` on an up to date Amazon Linux Server (using init, not systemd) I see the following:

```
LABEL=/         /           ext4    defaults,noatime        1       1
tmpfs           /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults                0       0
devpts          /dev/pts    devpts  gid=5,mode=620          0       0
sysfs           /sys        sysfs   defaults                0       0
proc            /proc       proc    defaults                0       0
/dev/sdf        /data       ext3    defaults                1       1
/dev/sdg        /mail       ext3    defaults                1       1
/dev/sdh        /backup     ext3    defaults                1       1

/dev/sdi        /data2      ext4    defaults                0       2
```

I want to add the last entry, and thought `0 2` is the proper setting for the `dump` and `pass` attributes. However, I see that other non root volumes have `1 1`. I believe `dump` is not relevant anymore.

Do these values really matter?

Should I set them to `0 2`?

Answer (score 8):

### Yes they matter, but not as much as they used to.

There's a lot of historical doco around that describes these things.  How apposite that doco is depends from what operating system you have and how you administer your system.

For example:  As M. Dickey says, if you still run the `dump` command, then the information in the `freq` column very much *does* matter, as it tells `dump` what to do. Conversely, if you are in the same boat as the answerer at https://superuser.com/a/247527/38062 , then the information in the `dump` column is probably not used by anything in your system.

The way that operating systems work in this area has changed significantly, and the relevance of these columns has changed.

Historically, one ran `fsck` in a boot-time script, with options that told it to read `/etc/fstab` and process all entries in pass-number order.  And there's copious doco instructing you to pick specific values for pass numbers in the `passno` column, as you are alluding to in the question.

That doco is out of date.  The world has changed.

### systemd operating systems

On systemd operating systems, `fsck` doesn't have that responsibility any more.

The native configuration format for systemd is the *unit*, which can be amongst other things a *service unit* or a *mount unit*.  systemd's service management proper operates solely in terms of those.  Your `/etc/fstab` database *is converted into* mount and service units by a program named `systemd-fstab-generator`.  This program is a *generator*, a type of ancillary utility whose job is to create unit files on the fly.  It generates `.mount` units that mount the volumes and `.service` units that run `systemd-fsck` (which chains to `fsck` after setting up a client-server connection to a server that displays progress information) against individual volumes.  `/etc/fstab` is effectively a *source file* and it is not the native control/configuration system.

The operation of `systemd-fstab-generator` completely ignores the `freq` column of `/etc/fstab`.  And it only cares whether the `passno` column is zero or non-zero.  If the latter, it generates references that cause the invocation of a `systemd-fsck@device.service` service to run `fsck`.  If the former, it does not.  So there's no difference if you choose 2, 1, or indeed 17035.

### nosh

The nosh toolset also converts `/etc/fstab` to native form, which in the nosh case is a suite of *service bundles*.  Its program for doing this is `convert-fstab-services`.  This can be run explicitly, or one can make use of the auto-conversion system in `/etc/system-control/convert/` to update service bundles whenever `/etc/fstab` changes.

Again, the `freq` column is ignored.  (Don't be confused by the `dump@device` service bundles that it creates.  That's to do with BSD crash dumping, not to do with filesystem backup via the `dump` command.)  And again the only thing that matters about the `passno` column is that it is greater than zero, which is what causes a `fsck@directory` service bundle to be created and joined up to the `mount@directory` service bundle.

### differences with `noauto` and `fsck`

The upshot of both the nosh and the systemd way of doing things is that instead of a single `fsck` being run in a mode that scans `/etc/fstab` and decides what to do, at one single point in the system bootstrap (or two, as in the case of the BSD `rc.d` system which tries to distinguish "background" from "foreground" volumes), running `fsck` is triggered by starting the individual "mount" services.

The filesystems that aren't mounted at bootstrap (because they are marked `noauto`) thus do not have their `fsck`s run at bootstrap.

### bootstrap `fsck` that does nothing anyway

Whilst `passno` matters inasmuch as it controls the generation of nosh service bundles or system service units that (indirectly) run `fsck` against individual volumes; sometimes that `fsck` is effectively a no-operation.  Some filesystem formats simply don't have `fsck` tools that can operate in the "unattended preen" mode than one needs for these bootstrap-time/mount-time `fsck` invocations.

This is the case for at least:

- [Debian's `fsck.btrfs`](https://sources.debian.net/src/btrfs-tools/4.3-1/fsck.btrfs/#L9)
- [Debian's `fsck.xfs`](https://sources.debian.net/src/xfsprogs/4.3.0/fsck/xfs_fsck.sh/)

For such filesystem types, the practical effect of `passno` is thus nil.  Set it to zero, no `fsck` service will run.  Set it to non-zero, the `fsck` service that runs invokes a program that does nothing.

### Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236968/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*`/etc/fstab` conversion*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/nosh/guide/fstab.html).  *nosh Guide*.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*External formats*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/nosh/guide/external-formats.html).  *nosh Guide*.
- [*`fsck -A` checks filesystems listed as `noauto`*](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=30883).  Debian bug #30883.  1998-12-19.
- [*`e2fsck` returns wrong error code for mount with `noauto` option*](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=459090).  Redhat bug #459090.  2008-08-14.
- Jorge Almeida (2011-02-26). [*`fsck` with `noauto`*](http://mailman.celestial.com/pipermail/linux-users/2011-February/146606.html).  linux-users.

Answer (score 0):

The [`dump`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dump) program is relevant if you backup your system.  Whether you backup a specific non-root filesystem, or just rely upon `fsck` to repair it, is your choice (assuming that you are talking about your personal computer).

Further reading:

- [Recommended fstab settings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17725/recommended-fstab-settings)
- [stab: When do you use the “dump” and “fsck” options?](https://superuser.com/questions/247523/fstab-when-do-you-use-the-dump-and-fsck-options)