# /etc/fstab and parallel filesystem check (fsck)

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, fsck

**FSCK(8)** says:

> The root filesystem will be checked first unless the `-`P  option is specified (see below). After that, filesystems will be checked in the order specified by the `fs_passno`  (the sixth) field in the /etc/fstab  file. Filesystems with a `fs_passno` value of 0 are skipped and are not checked at all. Filesystems with a `fs_passno`  value of greater than zero will be checked in order, with filesystems with the lowest `fs_passno`  number being checked first. **If there are multiple filesystems with the same pass number, `fsck`  will attempt to check them in parallel, although it will avoid running multiple filesystem checks on the same physical disk.**
>
> ...
>
> **Hence, a very common configuration in /etc/fstab  files is to set the
>   root filesystem to have a `fs_passno`  value of 1 and to set all other
>   filesystems to have a `fs_passno`  value of 2. This will allow `fsck` to
>   automatically run filesystem checkers in parallel if it is
>   advantageous to do so.** System administrators might choose not to use
>   this configuration if they need to avoid multiple filesystem checks
>   running in parallel for some reason – for example, if the machine in
>   question is short on memory so that excessive paging is a concern.

I have one physical disk on my machine, with two filesystems one vfat this is the ESP and the other is ext4 this is mounted on root `/`, each having fs_passno value of 1. The first paragraph in the manual page states that `fsck` avoids *"multiple filesystem checks on the same physical disk."*

Confusingly the second paragraph implies that filesystems with `fs_passno` of value 2  will be run in parallel and does not say that they might not run parallel on the *same disk.* In my case, what would be the case? Parallel or not parallel?

Comment: It is important to realize that all of this is moot as of Ubuntu 16, which employs systemd and organizes filesystem checking via service units emitted by `systemd-fstab-generator`.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236953/

Comment: Also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248534/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where exactly lies your confusion. First, all FS with `fs_passno=1` will be checked. If they are on the same physical media (your situation), the check will be sequential: VFAT first, then `/`, or the other way round. Then all FS with `fs_passno=2` will be checked, and so on.

Comment: "and to set all other filesystems to have a `fs_passno` value of 2. This will allow `fsck` to automatically run filesystem checkers in parallel if it is advantageous to do so." It says here it'll run the filesystem checker in parallel and it didn't mention that except for the same physical disk. The idea is to make the filesystem checker to run in parallel whenever possible perhaps? As such other than root we set `fs_passno=2` for all  so that when a filesystem is on different device the checker runs the check in parallel, since they have the same value `2` but on difference devices.

Comment: @direprobs Exactly. FS checks should be run in parallel whenever possible. `fs_passno` is here to ensure a specific order (i.e. in case of a crash you want your system up as soon as possible => you give `/` the number 1, `/var` and `/home` the number 2 and `/mnt/archives` the number 3). And since there is no gain checking in parallel on the same device (hardware bottleneck), the checker ensures checks are done sequentially on a given physical device.