# if fstab ending is 0 0 - then there will be never any fsck?

Tags: fsck, sles

If I can see in /etc/fstab on a SLES12 machine:

```
/dev/vg/lvtmp   /tmp                 xfs       defaults,nodev,nosuid 0 0
```

that means the "/tmp" will never get fsck'ed?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [`fstab(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html) man page

> ```
> The sixth field (fs_passno).
>           This field is used by fsck(8) to determine the order in which
>           filesystem checks are done at boot time.  The root filesystem
>           should be specified with a fs_passno of 1.  Other filesystems
>           should have a fs_passno of 2.  Filesystems within a drive will
>           be checked sequentially, but filesystems on different drives
>           will be checked at the same time to utilize parallelism
>           available in the hardware.  Defaults to zero (don't fsck) if
>           not present.
> ```

The `fs_passno` is used by the `fsck` program to determine the order in which filesystem checks are done at reboot time. That is, if the sixth field is not present or zero, a value of zero is returned and `fsck` will assume that the filesystem does not need to be checked.

Comment: The world has changed.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/248578/5132